# Component display won't updated on V-if condition change

Tags: javascript, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-reactivity

I'm not used to reactivity in VueJs. Here is my situation.
It's a Django + Vue3 CDN Single Page Application project which means that I create the components as object.
I have a sub component that I need to display when a set of data is ready.
But since the request takes a long time, I've only placed my condition on the subcomponent.

When the value for the conditional render get to be true, I would like the subcomponent to be displayed.
Once again, I don't know how to set that variable to be reactive.

```
let mainComponent = {
    component: { 'child-component': childComponent },
    data(){
       return {
          displayModal: false
          otherData: '',
          }
    },
    mounted: {
         axios.get(apiUrl).then((res) => {
               this.otherData = res.data;
               this.displayModal = true;
         }
    },
    template: `<div>
                   <child-component v-if="displayModal" :child-Props="otherData"></child-component>
               </div>
               `
    }
```

The situation I get is at the start the display value is false but when it becomes true, the child-component doesn't render.
How can I make this reactive to the value change ?

Comment: Why don't you use pinia or reactive for state management

Comment: I'm checking that right away.

Comment: I am using pinia, but my v-for is not running, because the variable I've set in onMounted doesn't have a value when the page renders, and I don't see anything unless I click away and click back. Now checking how to solve this. I already have a v-if but that's failing apparently and page is not re-rendering when value arrives.

Comment: @Dgloria Have you solved the issue yet ? 
You need to place your v-if above the v-for div. Where is the value coming from ? api request or props ?

Comment: Romain, yes, I didn't add the store name before the variable name. was something like v-if="useStore.myVar". So user error.